# Optimizing MySQL query across multiple rows

Tags: mysql, optimization

my current query looks something like this. I've been trying to optimize it but I got no luck so far.
My goal is to get the difference in stat_value between the current day and the previous day for every player and then order it.
The current code works fine, but feels unoptimized to me.
The ? values are filled in using Java.

```
SELECT t1.stat_value - 
       (SELECT stat_value 
          FROM leaderheadsplayersdata_daily t2 
         WHERE t2.player_id = t1.player_id 
           AND t2.day = ? 
           AND t2.stat_type = ? 
         LIMIT 1
       ) as sum
     , (SELECT name 
          FROM leaderheadsplayers 
         WHERE leaderheadsplayers.player_id = t1.player_id 
         LIMIT 1
       ) 
    FROM leaderheadsplayersdata_daily t1 
   WHERE day = ? 
     AND stat_type = ? 
   ORDER 
      BY sum DESC LIMIT 100
```

Table structure:

This is the main table containing the player id and username.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `leaderheadsplayers` 
(player_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
,uuid VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL UNIQUE
,name VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
,last_join DATETIME
) ENGINE = InnoDB
```

This is the table containing the daily data.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS leaderheadsplayersdata_daily 
(player_id INTEGER NOT NULL
,stat_value DOUBLE NOT NULL
,stat_type VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
,day INTEGER NOT NULL
,FOREIGN KEY (player_id) REFERENCES leaderheadsplayers(player_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
,PRIMARY KEY(player_id, stat_type, day)
) ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Describing your table structure would help in suggesting an answer

Comment: Added database structure.

Comment: Can you provide the output of using EXPLAIN on your query?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE (you have) and INSERT (you haven't) statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set (you haven't) that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Thanks for all the support. The answer about 'JOIN' seems to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you only have 2 days, you can do a double join on the `leaderheadsplayersdata_daily` table.

It would look something like this:

```
SELECT
    p.player_id,
    p.name,
    (dc.stat_value-dp.statvalue) AS difference,
    dc.day,
FROM leaderheadsplayers p
JOIN leaderheadsplayersdata_daily dc ON p.player_id = dc.player_id
JOIN leaderheadsplayersdata_daily dp ON p.player_id = dp.player_id and dp.day = (dc.day-1)
WHERE dc.day = ?CURRENT_DAY?
ORDER BY difference DESC
```

`dc` stands for "date current". `dp` stands for "date previous". `p` stands for "player".

For good performance, add indexes on the columns `player_id` (in both tables) and `day`.

Sorry, I didn't test, have not ideea if I have syntax errors or stuff. Also, please replace `?CURRENT_DAY?` with the actual day and add other conditions in `WHERE` clause, as needed

If `ORDER BY difference DESC` does not work, just do `ORDER BY (dc.stat_value-dp.statvalue) DESC`.

You have a lot of subqueries, you look like you could take a look at some [documentation about JOINs](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp). They're really useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The query is incredibly fast right now.

Comment: Glad to be of service. :)

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, you can try the following. Let me know how this version that uses implicit triple join fare with the one suggested above that uses explicit triple join. Thanks.

```
SELECT t3.player_id, improvement FROM 
   (SELECT t1.player_id as player_id, (t1.stat_value - t2.stat_value) as improvement 
      FROM leaderheadsplayersdata_daily t1 INNER JOIN leaderheadsplayersdata_daily t2 
         on t1.player_id = t2.player_id and t1.stat_type = t2.stat_type 
            and t2.day = ? and t1.day = ?) as t3 
   INNER JOIN leaderheadsplayers on 
      t3.player_id = leaderheadsplayers.player_id 
          ORDER BY improvement DESC LIMIT 100;
```